# Add custom events to website user's google calendar using calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api, mobile-website

I envision a user visiting my mobile website (not an app), finding an important event with an associated date, being asked if they want to sync this date/event to their google calendar, saying yes, and my website depositing this event into their google calendar.

Their would be many events, and they would be based on user input, so it wouldn't work to just sync my calendar with theirs.  I would have to insert a custom date/event into their calendar so they could track it.

Hopefully this makes sense.  I haven't seen anything like this on the web but I'm sure it exists.

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Calendar Event Publisher Guide](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/1186917?hl=en). It sounds like it will meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions...it's close but not quite.  I should have been more clear.  I think this may involve google calendar API because I won't have an actual calendar to send events to other people's calendars.  I'll have to create the event on the fly depending on user input.  Any suggestions there?  Thanks!